# AST for current selected code in eclipse editor?

Tags: java, eclipse, editor, selection

I need to get the AST for the current selection in the java editor fo eclipse.
Basically I want to convert the selected java code in to some other form(maybe some other language or XML etc..). So I guess, I need to get the AST for the selection.
Currently I am able to get the selection as simple text. Is there any way out for such problem?
Thanks already!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are a number of handy tools for JDT plugin developers, especially the [AST View](http://www.eclipse.org/jdt/ui/astview/index.php) which does pretty much what you are looking for. So, all you need to do is grab the code for AST View and check how it is done.

The plugin can be installed from the following update site: http://www.eclipse.org/jdt/ui/update-site

[image: JDT ASTView]

Use the plugin spy (read more about it in [this article](http://zvikico.typepad.com/problog/2008/06/eclipse-34-hidden-treasures.html)) to start digging into the view classes.

You are traveling into less trivial (and often undocumented) areas of JDT, developing your code digging skills will greatly improve your performance.

Comment: Thanks, I have just started browsing the code and I am already feeling optimistic. Will let you know.

Comment: @zvikico, thanks. Now I am able to get the ASTNode for the selected text. Now I need a ASTVisitor that could give me fully resolved code of the node. i.e. each type name should be fully qualified name so that I can serialize it and do some magic over it.
Any idea?? Thanks!

Comment: I can get code of form String x;
But what I need is java.lang.String x;
Any ideas?

Comment: You have a node. Nicely done. The key is in the node.resolveBinding() method(s) which returns IBinding implementor. For example, a VariableDeclaration will resolve to IVariableBinding which has a getType() method which return ITypeBinding. Once you get the ITypeBinding, it will give you all the information you need on the fully qualified type.

Comment: If it worked for you, you might as well mark it as the right answer :-)

Comment: How did you get `ASTNode for the selected text`? Is it possible to get `ASTNode` only with `ITextSelection` (which has line number, offset information)?

Comment: @SurajChandran: It would be nice of you to post your (partial) solution for others to learn from.

Answer (score 4):

The following Code provides you the AST Node of the current selected Code from the CompilationUnitEditor.

```
        ITextEditor editor = (ITextEditor) HandlerUtil.getActiveEditor(event);
        ITextSelection sel  = (ITextSelection) editor.getSelectionProvider().getSelection();
        ITypeRoot typeRoot = JavaUI.getEditorInputTypeRoot(editor.getEditorInput());
        ICompilationUnit icu = (ICompilationUnit) typeRoot.getAdapter(ICompilationUnit.class);
        CompilationUnit cu = parse(icu);
        NodeFinder finder = new NodeFinder(cu, sel.getOffset(), sel.getLength());
        ASTNode node = finder.getCoveringNode();
```

The JavaUI is the entry point to the JDT UI plugin.

Comment: where did you get the parse function?

Answer (score 1):

Use the method `org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.EditorUtility.getActiveEditorJavaInput()`. That returns the Java element edited in the current active editor. The return type is `org.eclipse.jdt.core.IJavaElement`, but if it's a Java file that's being edited, the run time type will be `org.eclipse.jdt.core.ICompilationUnit`.

To get the AST, i.e., the `org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.CompilationUnit`, you can use the following code:

```
public static CompilationUnit getCompilationUnit(ICompilationUnit icu,
        IProgressMonitor monitor) {
    final ASTParser parser = ASTParser.newParser(AST.JLS3);
    parser.setSource(icu);
    parser.setResolveBindings(true);
    final CompilationUnit ret = (CompilationUnit) parser.createAST(monitor);
    return ret;
}
```

Keep in mind that this is for Java >= 5. For earlier versions you'll need to switch the argument to `ASTParser.newParser()`.

I realize that this question was answered but I wanted to shed light on the EditorUtility class, which is quite useful here.

Comment: This method is in the internal package, you should not use it.

Comment: Well, I guess that would depend on whether or not you're writing internal code :).

Answer (score 0):

IIRC, each node in the Eclipse AST contains an offset. All you need to do is to compute the offsets for the part of the code you are interested in then walk the AST to select the nodes within those offsets.