# Is it possible to create a command line JDT application?

Tags: eclipse, command-line, eclipse-pdt

I want to create a command line application which does analysis of Java code. The Eclipse JDT seems like the right tool for the job, however every tutorial I can find on the JDT starts up the JDT as an Eclipse plugin.

I would expect something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    IWorkspace workspace = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace();
    ...
}
```

to get started. However getWorkspace() throws an exception that the service is not started.

Comment: I asked a similar (not too similar) question here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1681218/is-it-possible-to-decouple-the-code-indexing-capabilities-of-eclipse) that may be of interest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to leverage JDT you have to start eclipse. You can use the extension point "org.eclipse.core.runtime.applications" to create a minimal application that starts from the command line.

1. Create a new Plugin-Project.
2. Add "org.eclipse.core.runtime" and "org.eclipse.core.resources" to the dependencies.
3. Create an extension for "org.eclipse.core.runtime.applications".
4. Create a class that implements "org.eclipse.equinox.app.IApplication" and reference it in your extension.

My plugin.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?eclipse version="3.4"?>
<plugin>
   <extension
         id="id2"
         point="org.eclipse.core.runtime.applications">
      <application
            cardinality="singleton-global"
            thread="main"
            visible="true">
         <run class="testapplication.Application1">
         </run>
      </application>
   </extension>
</plugin>
```

MANIFEST.MF:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: TestApplication
Bundle-SymbolicName: TestApplication;singleton:=true
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0.qualifier
Bundle-Activator: testapplication.Activator
Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.core.runtime,
 org.eclipse.core.resources
Bundle-ActivationPolicy: lazy
Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-1.6
```

Application1.java:

```
package testapplication;

import org.eclipse.core.resources.ResourcesPlugin;
import org.eclipse.equinox.app.IApplication;
import org.eclipse.equinox.app.IApplicationContext;

public class Application1 implements IApplication {

    @Override
    public Object start(IApplicationContext context) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Hello eclipse at "
                + ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot().getRawLocation());
        return IApplication.EXIT_OK;
    }

    @Override
    public void stop() {
        // nothing to do at the moment
    }

}
```

Output is:

> Hello eclipse at D:/Arne/workspaces/runtime-TestApplication.id2

Comment: Thanks Arne! Worked like a charm. Showing the files was especially helpful to a newbie to the Eclipse/OSGi magic.

I was about to sacrifice my neighbors goat to the cause, but I'll have to save it for when things really get nasty ...

Answer (score 0):

You want to make sure you have started Eclipse first.  Use the EclipseStarter class to get things running and then you can use the methods on ResourcesPlugin.

Comment: I found the EclipseStarter class, but how do you plug into it?

Comment: You have to define an Eclipse application for it to run, and it will run that application.  You need to put the org.eclipse.osgi plugin in your classpath.  Your application will implement IApplication, which has essentially start() and stop().  From inside of the start() method you can kick off your work.