# new project wizard plugin

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I need to create an eclipse project that does the following:
a. Add an entry in the File->New->Project list
b. When the user clicks on this pop-up a dialog where I ask for some information
c. On clicking okay, I want to generate java code which implements certain interfaces

I know how to do steps a and b. how do I generate do I achieve step c?

Comment: You should accept the correct answers on your other questions. That will motivate more people to give you answers at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you not only need Java code, but a whole Java project: There is a nice tutorial how to do this here: http://sdqweb.ipd.kit.edu/wiki/JDT_Tutorial:_Creating_Eclipse_Java_Projects_Programmatically

Comment: also found this link to be useful. http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseJDT/article.html

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1898084/is-it-possible-to-create-a-command-line-jdt-application explains how to setup a project in eclipse to use JDT standalone.