# How do I get 'IStructuredSelection' from editor when user selects on text?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I am working on eclipse-plugin.

I have successfully added a context menu (while user is in Java editor and right click in the editor) and connected it partially to action class that I created.

Apparently, when user clicks on any element on the editor (any text) and right click to open the context menu, and select the menu that I created, the plugin will start tracing the selection that user selects. However, the selection that it trace is always in instance of `ITextSelection` which I cannot do anything useful with it. I want to get selection as an instance of `IStructuredSelection` so that my plugin can play with it.
Is there anyway that I can do that?

```java
public class MyPluginAction extends ActionDelegate implements IEditorActionDelegate {

    public void run(IAction action) {

    }

    public void selectionChanged(IAction action, ISelection selection) {
        if(selection instanceof IStructuredSelection){
            System.out.println("IStructure");
        } else if(selection instanceof ITextSelection){
            System.out.println("IText");
        }
    }

    public void setActiveEditor(IAction action, IEditorPart targetEditor) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
}
```

Comment: What aspect of `IStructuredSelection` is the useful part that you want to play with? It'd be just a list of objects...

Comment: I want to fetch `IJavaElement` from IStructuredSelection so that I can use my Refactoring plugin with that IJavaElement. It seems that some of other internal refactorings work when an user right clicks on the IJavaElement. I just wanted to know what would be the best way to do that.....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you select text from an Editor you'll get always an ITextSelection, getting an IStructuredSelection does not make sense at all. I guess [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1636131/ast-for-current-selected-code-in-eclipse-editor) will solve your problem.

Comment: Then, how does some of other internal refactorings in Java directly work with selected IJavaElement within Editor?